# How do I set the default .zshrc (oh-my-zsh) for users?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've installed oh-my-zsh and have changed theme and customized it for the root user.
How can I make these mods available for all users for which I will set zsh as default shell?

Comment: try placing your `~/.zshrc` in  `/etc/zshrc` I'm not sure thou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh-my-zsh is best installed per user. Users can fiddle with the source, adding custom plug-ins to their `.oh-my-zsh/custom` directory for instance. The auto-update feature also wouldn't work on a system wide install.

To help them get started, you can provide new users with a recent clone of `.oh-my-zsh` and a `.zshrc` template. Adding these to `/etc/skel` for instance.

I'd also question whether root needs oh-my-zsh or the same zsh config as a normal user. It's best to avoid spending too much time as root anyways.

If you really want to, you can symlink your own .oh-my-zsh and .zshrc to another user home directory including root's.

If you have to enforce a global config. There's a global `zshrc` (either `/etc/zshrc` or `/etc/zsh/zshrc` depending on your system) that's loaded before the user `.zshrc`. If you're impersonating all users on the system, you could always load your oh-my-zsh config from there.

Finally, you'll probably want to change the login shell of oh-my-zsh user to `zsh` as well. Look into `/etc/passwd`, `chsh` and `adduser.conf` for details.

Answer (score 0):

If that file is on all user directory then zsh should automatically catch it and use it as source. So i think you should put that file on every user directory who intent to use that file.